# googlebot visiting my google analytics virtual pageview URLs

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, googlebot

For a certain group of pages on my site, I send google analytics a virtual pageview.  So, as an example, instead of the page being /username, I track it with google analytics using /profile/username like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/profile/username']);
```

Works great it seems.  Except I'm seeing TONS of the above virtual URLs in my website logs with googlebot as the user-agent!  Why is google visiting my virtual URLs?  Did I do something wrong above?  Is this normal?

Comment: So, questions to potentially eliminate causes: Have you setup the Webmaster Tools/Google Analytics integration? Is it possible someone on your site used the top URLs in Google Analytics to populate a Site Map? Do you use In-Page Analytics frequently?

Comment: On Webmaster Tools, I don't see any setting for a Google Analytics integration.  We have not setup a Site Map yet.  I don't know what In-Page Analytics is.  Basically nobody knows about this virtual pageview URL except google analytics.

Comment: Bizarre. Looks like this is a long-running, unresolved thing: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=7d8d0070a18a8616&hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a [long-running problem, going back to December 2009](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=7d8d0070a18a8616&hl=en).

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any explanation as to why or how this is happening.

Comment: not possible this is anything but googlebot, because only google analytics would know about my virtual pageview URLs.  I'm looking in my access log.

Comment: Ohhh, weird. I misunderstood your question; I thought you were seeing it in Google Analytics, not in your access log. That's really interesting